# How create a constraint with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I create a constraint with Hibernate? I'm mapping two classes, "Team" and "Match", but I want that a match JUST can happens if the teams are from the same League. The way that I'm doing right now I can create a match with teams from differents leagues (which isn't interesting in this case). 
Is there some annotation that "wraps" my teams, home and away, just being from one league? Or I have to do this in my system?

Thanks.

```
@Table(name = "match")
@Entity
public class Match implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_league")
private League league;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_home", referencedColumnName="id")
private Team home;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_away", referencedColumnName="id")
private Team away;
@Column
private Integer goalsHome;
@Column
private Integer goalsAway;
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
private Date matchDate;
```

and

```
@Table(name="team")
@Entity
public class Team implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
@Column(length = 55)
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_league")
private League league;
@OneToMany
private List<Match> match;
```

Comment: do you mean like a `JOIN` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually, I translated my classes wrong. Now it's correct, thanks.

Comment: @ScaryWombat but join isn't used only for consults?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you are meaning.  Can you show what you want by making SQL?

Comment: Is a league associated with a team, or with a match?  I think it should only be associated with a team, so remove `League` from your `Match` entity.

Comment: @Hawk -- I can't think of one. Generally constraints are used for a single record. What about making an update view in the database. Then you could enforce more complicated rules with the sql in the update view.

Comment: Hibernate's `@Check` annotation in theory can do this, but the thing is that the `Match` entity would need to check the fields of foreign key entities, not directly in the table.  You might have to implement a trigger to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My plan was that a League have matches with teams from that league and teams are part of a specific league, so I thought that way was correct.

That's my problem, I don't have a lot of experience with the Hibernate, JPA and MySQL, so I didn't know if is possible with one annotation or not. I'll check about the trigger, thanks!

Comment: I understand your requirement, and what I'm saying is that I don't think it is possible to enforce this using Hibernate alone.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I don't have any knowledge about update views, I'll check them too, but the little that I searched about doesn't appears to work how I'd like. Thanks!

Comment: I resolved with the trigger, the classes are the same, but I've added an trigger before the insert.

Thanks a lot for the help, guys, and sorry, my english is a little rusty hahah.